# CodeIgniter controller model 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm getting a 404 error on my CodeIgniter site, I've had a look around at the other answers and playing with the .htaccess but yet to solve. Its located on my domain.co.uk/admin

**Controller -**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Projects extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->model('project');
    $data['projects']=$this->project->get_projects();
    echo"<pre>";print_r($data['projects']);echo"</pre>";
}
}
```

Model -

```
<?php

class Project extends CI_Model{

function get_projects($num=10,$start=0){
    $this->$db->select()->from('projects')->where('active',1)->order_by('date_added','desc')->limit($num,$start);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
}
```

I've also added these routes -

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'projects';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Currently have this .htaccess in my domain/admin folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Can anyone see why I might be getting a 404 error

Comment: Is your file name Projects.php or projects.php

Comment: Is it working on `domain.co.uk/index.php/admin`?

Comment: its a lowercase p on "projects.php", and no it's not working on any paths I've tired a few

Answer (score 0):

What do you have on your `$route['default_controller']` variable? (It shoulds be defined in \application\config).

If you have `$route['default_controller'] = "Projects"`, your index URL should be `domain/admin/index.php/projects` or `domain/admin/projects`*

*You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

On codeigniter 3 you should always have your first letter of your class and file name as upper case on models and controllers and libraries.

Also I would rename projects model to Model_project.php because codeigniter may get confused if have same names.

Model **Model_project.php**

```
class Model_project extends CI_Model {

}
```

Controller **Project.php**

```
class Project extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('model_project');
    }
}
```

You may need to set up your routes

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a codeigniter 3.0 then update your MODEL and CONTROLLER starting with capital letters and also don't give a same name for both model and controller as you have given in the above code.
For example:

```
class Projects extends CI_Controller {
   //code comes here
}
```

In this Projects the name is absolutely fine but mark it that you file name should also start with capital letter that is Project.php
Another for model:

```
class Projects_model extends CI_Model {
       //code comes here
    }
```

This is the way to make a proper way to work with codeigniter and also i have already told you that the MODEL and CONTROLLER filename must be started with the capital letter.

Thank You.. hope it will help you